# Python 3.7.8 shell not finding pyutogui module

Tags: python

pip installer has said the statement has been satisfied but I cant import the pyautogui module into the shell

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install pyautogui`

Comment: @Blaine Thomas If you have another version of python installed on your system, check which version of python your module has been installed to.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it with conda...

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui
```